# CosmosDB Change Feed in multiple regions with Multi-Master configuration

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

The system I'm working on has multiple environments, each running in separate Azure regions. Our CosmosDB is replicated to these regions and **multi-region writes are enabled**. We're using the default consistency model (Session).

We have azure functions that use the CosmosDb trigger deployed in all three regions. Currently these use the same lease prefix which means that only one function processes changes at any given time. I know that we can set each
region to have different lease prefixes to enable concurrent processing but I'd like to solidify my understanding before taking this step.

My question is around the behaviour of the change feed with regards to replication in this scenario? According to this link https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/42248#issuecomment-552207409 data is first converged on the primary region and then the change feed is updated.

Other resources I've read seem to suggest that each region has it's own change feed which will update upon replication. Also, the previous link recommends only running a change feed processor in the primary region in multi-master.

In an ideal world, I'd like change feed processors in each region to handle local writes quickly. These functions will make updates to CosmosDB and I also want to avoid issues with replication. My question is - **what is the actual behavior in a multi master configuration (and by extension the correct architecture)?**. Is it "safe" to use per-region change feed processors, or should we use a single processor in the primary region?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have per-region Change Feed Processor's that only process the local changes, because the Change Feed in each region contains the local writes plus the replicated writes from each other region.

Technically you can use a single Change Feed Processor deployment connecting to one of the regions to process events on all the regions.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me and clarifying this so quickly. I had considered using region-specific lease prefixes and dealing with the inevitable conflicts with a conflict resolution policy but this seems pointless and error prone. It was also driven by my initial fear of high replication latency, in part because I couldn't find a solid guarantee for this, but I'm seing writes being replicated in well under 100ms worst case so that fear seems to be unjustified. Thanks again.